# Default Constructor Calls

Tags: c++

I am studying for a C++ exam using a practice exam. I am having issues determining when certain constructors are called. The code is -

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class Fraction
{
  private:
   int numerator, denominator;
  public:
   Fraction( int = 0, int = 1 );
   friend ostream& operator<<( ostream&, const Fraction& );
  };

 void debug( Fraction, Fraction );
 Fraction task( Fraction&, const Fraction& );

int main()
  {
    Fraction * A[6], * B; // Line 1
    Fraction C( 3 ), D( C ); // Line 2
    Fraction E[4], F = D; // Line 3
    Fraction G, H( 3, 4 ); // Line 4
    debug( C, D ); // Line 5
    B = new Fraction; // Line 6
    F = task( H, C );
    delete B;
    return 0;
  }

 void debug( Fraction X, Fraction Y )
 {
   cout << X << endl << Y << endl;
 }

 Fraction task( Fraction& X, const Fraction& Y )
 {
   Fraction Z;
   Z = Fraction( 5, 2 ); // Line 7
   return 1; // Line 8
 }
```

Now, I thought that the default copy constructor was called in 3 types of instances.

Example 1 -

```
        Fraction A(1,2);

        Fraction B(A);
```

Example 2 -

```
        Fraction A(1,2);

        Fraction A = B;
```

3 - When an object is returned from a function

4 - When an object is passed as a parameter into a function

There are two questions I cannot seem to answer -

Question 1 - Consider the source code above. When the
statements labeled "Line 3" and "Line 4" are compiled and executed, how many
calls to the constructors for class "Fraction" will be made for each of
those statements?

The answer is - D) Line 3: 5 calls Line 4: 2 calls

The answer to this question is D. However, when I answer it I get a different result -

```
    Fraction E[4], F = D; // Line 3
```

I see that the default constructor is called 5 times for the array E[4], but I thought this this statement was also equivalent to -

```
    Fraction E[4], Fraction F(D);
```

Therefore, the default constructor is called 5 times and the copy constructor once. Evidently, this is incorrect and as constructors are only called 5 times. I do not see where my error is.

My other issue is in the following question -

1. Consider the source code in Figure 2 (on the previous page). When the
   statements labeled "Line 7" and "Line 8" are compiled and executed, how many
   calls to the constructors for class "Fraction" will be made for each of
   those statements?

   The answer is - D) Line 7: 1 call Line 8: 1 call

   ```
       Fraction task( Fraction& X, const Fraction& Y )
       {
         Fraction Z;
         Z = Fraction( 5, 2 ); // Line 7
         return 1; // Line 8
       }
   ```

   I originally thought that the default constructor would be called to create a temp object for Fraction(5,2) and then the copy constructor would copy Fraction( 5, 2 ) to Z. Is this actually an operation for the default assignment operator? As for line 8, is this calling the copy constructor because it is returning an object of type Fraction?

A few more questions while I am here -

would -

```
debug(B, C)
```

call the copy constructor twice to pass copies of Fraction objects B and C?

and is -

```
F = task( H, C );
```

calling the default assignment operator as well as F already exists as an initialized Fraction object?

Comment: Why dont you just run through this code in a debugger?

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't answer your question. The program is making use of default constructors. I trying to make note when the default constructors get called. If there is a debugger that will tell me, that would be great. However, I would like understand why I am accounting for more calls than the answer to the questions allot. As in line 3, I am accounting for one more call than the answer. Something about my logic is wrong.

Comment: Does your code compile? At least not on g++ 4.7.2

Comment: I am not sure. It was just sample code from a practice exam posted on my professor's web page. Presumably, it should compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to know when default constructor and copy constructor are called.

For your first question:

```
Fraction E[4], F = D; // Line 3
```

`E[4]` is an array of `Fraction` objects, which calls the default constructor 4 times since you did not explicitly call any other constructor to initialize those objects. Since at Line 2 object `D` is already constructed, therefore, `F` is constructed using the copy constructor, in this case, the compiler generates one for you since you did not define one for yourself.
So in this case, 4 default constructor calls and one copy constructor call.
At Line 4, both objects calls the default constructor, so two times on default ctor.

```
debug(B, C)
call the copy constructor twice to pass copies of Fraction objects B and C?
```

Yes, since parameters are passed by value in `debug` function, so copy constructor is called for both `B` and `C`

In general, copy constructor are called in the following situation:

1. When instantiating one object with an existing object (as `F= D` or `F(D)`)
2. When passing an object by value.
3. When an object is returned from a function by value.

Hope that this gives you enough information to understand the code.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I forgot that declaring the capacity of an array is explicit, not the number of elements + 1. If I may ask, say I declare a Fraction F(1,2) and then copy an existing object into it, such as F = Fraction(3,4). Would this call the default constructor and default assignment operator?

Comment: @Jonnywalkerr   Fraction F(1,2) will call default constructor, F(3,4) calls default constructor too. Since F is already created, F =Fraction(3,4) will call the copy assignment operator, which the compiler generates for you in this case.

Comment: So, the compiler generates both a copy constructor and an copy assignment operator. The copy constructor is called to deal with copying data members from an object, member-by-member, to a newly declared object. The difference between this and the default assignment operator is that the assignment operator copies items from an object to an object that has already been initialized. Is this correct? Also, for something like F = Fraction(3,4), is it only the copy assignment operator getting called? Or is the default constructor called as well to generate a temp object Fraction(3,4)?

Comment: @Jonnywalkerr Yes, you basically got it. F= Fraction(3,4) will first call the default ctor to create a temporary object then call copy assignment operator to assign to F, there is no copy constructor involved here.

Comment: Is the copy assignment operator considered a "constructor". According to this practice exam, F= Fraction(3,4) would call a single constructor. Would this be the default constructor for creating the temporary object?