# Which line calls the default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

Previous SO post consulted: [Default Constructor Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594290/default-constructor-calls)

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

struct item {
    std::string name;
    int price;
    // item() = default;
    item(std::string n, int p): name(n), price(p) {}
};

void createItems(std::unordered_map<std::string, item>& blah);

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, item> blah;
    createItems(blah);
    
    cout << blah["armor"].name << " " << blah["armor"].price << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

void createItems(std::unordered_map<std::string, item>& blah) {
    item i1{"armor", 1000};
    item i2{"amulet", 200};
    blah["armor"] = i1;
    blah["amulet"] = i2;
    return;
}
```

The error message when run:

```
  main.cpp:20:25:   required from here

  /usr/include/c++/11/tuple:1824:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘item::item()’
 1824 |         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:5: note: candidate: ‘item::item(std::string, int)’
   10 |     item(std::string n, int p): name(n), price(p) {}
      |     ^~~~
main.cpp:10:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
main.cpp:6:8: note: candidate: ‘item::item(const item&)’
    6 | struct item {
      |        ^~~~
main.cpp:6:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:6:8: note: candidate: ‘item::item(item&&)’
main.cpp:6:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

From my understanding, the default constructor is called but since I commented the line out the call results in an error.

**Question**: Why (and where) is the default constructor needed? My suspicion is that `blah["armor"]` calls the default constructor, but why?

Comment: `My suspicion is that blah["armor"] calls the default constructor` yes. `but why?` What else would it do if the key does not exist in the map?

Comment: Consider the epxression `blah["armor"]`. What do you expect to happen if the key doesn't exist? Which object would `blah["armor"] = i1;` assign to if it didn't elready exist? How would it exist if it wasn't default-constructed?

Comment: Thanks @tkausl thinking about this, it makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo Thanks for the explanation. Both comments as well as the answer make perfect sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As tkausl hinted at in their comment, the index operator is what needs the default constructor.

What the index operator does is

```
find tree location for key
if this location does not exist
  create location
  copy-construct key there
  default-construct value there
return reference to value at location
```

Step 5 needs the default constructor. And since everything needs to be resolved at compile time, it needs the default constructor even if you never actually use a non-existent key. (You do, though.)

If you don't have a default constructor, you can't use the index operator. Use `insert`, `emplace` or `try_emplace` add elements to the map, and `find` or `at` to look them up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, marked as answer.